# RxJs/Angular2 map function on http response not called

Tags: dictionary, angular, rxjs, observable, reactive

Ok, there must be something I don't understand regarding the `map()`function. I'd expect that in both cases of the subscription the term *mapped* is written to the console. However, it is not if the http response has a status code of 4xx.

```
http.get("http://my.domain/rest/path").map(
  data => {
    console.log("mapped");
    return data;
  }
).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log("good");
  },
  error => {
    console.log("bad");
  }
);
```

Any hints here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` function only proceeds 'good' data and not error. In real case, I'd expect different body data for `Ok` cases (real data) and `Bad Request` cases (error messages) too. To catch and handle error in `http.get` function, use `catch`:

```
let obs = http.get("http://my.domain/rest/path").map(
  data => {
    console.log("mapped");
    return data;
  }
).catch(err => console.log(err));

obs.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I see. However, it seems that whenever an exception is caught the Observable gets unsubscribed (according to my debugger see RxJs's catch.js:58 in beta11) and a subsequent ``subscribe`` results in  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
" Actually I need to subscribe and process the results even in case of an Http Status 4xx/5xx.

Comment: PS.: Just figured out that when I return an Observable.of(...) from the catch block, it would work.

Answer (score 2):

The Angular 2 `Http` client treats responses with `4xx` and `5xx` status codes [as errors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling). So the `map` operator does not receive an emitted response.

Note that if an error is thrown due to the response's status code, the error will contain `status` and `statusText` properties:

```
http.get("http://my.domain/rest/path").map(
  data => {
    console.log("mapped");
    return data;
  }
).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log("good");
  },
  error => {
    if (error.status) {
      console.log("somewhat bad: " + error.status);
    } else {
      console.log("really bad");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Ok. Without delving into the sources can I assume that http's ``get`` throws an exception on status 4xx/5xx which is (ignored by ``map`` and) caught internally by ``subscribe`` which, in turn, assigns the payload of the exception to its 2nd ``error`` function?

Comment: That's correct. If you want to handle the error in the composed observable, you could include a `catch` operator - as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. Since the ``catch`` block is what gets me ahead here, I've chose to pick Harry's answer as solution and +1 for both.

Comment: Cool. No worries.